# How to continue a network request when user moves app to the background during the request?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphcool

I am building a messaging app in react-native.

I have a problem where if the user is sending a message, then puts the app into the background before my redux (thunk) action containing all the network logic finishes, the message doesn't get created on the backend. However, I am still seeing the SUCCESS action come back from the action.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you!